# angularjs - How can I associate a label or attribute to a control in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have an angular app that is used in a CMS.  A marketing team can create a form by adding html to a widget by using plain html.  What I am trying to do is to capture the question asked in the form and the user response so I can save that to the question/answer pair to the db.

I can use ng-model to get the value entered, however, I am unsure how to get the question.  The solution can't require questions to be read from a js array.  They have to be entered in markup through a content widget.

I'm thinking something like `Label for`, ng-model type of behavior for a `<span>` or adding an attribute to the control that contains the question asked.

Thanks.

```
    <span ng-model="user.favoriteColor.label">Favorite color:</span>
    <input type="text" id="favoriteColor" ng-model="user.favoriteColor">
```

Here is a plunk of a basic example:
[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/g0dWOU1kMbrSi6FEPiZ3?p=preview)

My goal is to end up with an object that contains the value from the `<span>` or `label` for the question and the response.  It would look like this when I post:

```
    [
    {questionText: 'Favorite color?', answer: 'red'},
    {questionText: 'Favorite food?', answer: 'pizza'},
    etc...
    ]
```

Comment: @jrath can't use ng-model on hidden input

Comment: how are you question/answer pairs saved to your database?  Are they in the same table?

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is here. Not enough details provided about these questions and how they get stored

Comment: @RaniRadcliff yes, in the same table

Comment: create a directive to bind to your model... ng-model doesn't do what you need... there are no ready directives to your need, but it's a good and valid task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/ebmdtSKzBlPpGsKT1BTN?p=preview) to how I solved this issue.

```
    <span id="q1Label">Question 1:</span>
    <input type="text" id="q1" ng-model="questions[0].questionResponse" ng-blur="getQuestionAndAnswer($event,0)" />

    $scope.questions=[];
    $scope.getQuestionAndAnswer = function(event, arrayIndex) {
    var questionId = event.target.id;
    var questionLabelId = questionId + "Label";

    $scope.questions[arrayIndex].questionId = questionId;

    var questionText = document.getElementById(questionLabelId).textContent;
    $scope.questions[arrayIndex].questionText = questionText;

    $scope.questions.push({
    'questionText':questionText,
    'questionResponse': scope.questions[arrayIndex].questionResponse,
    'questionId': questionId
    });
    }
```